# у меня есть несколько объектов с одним классом(сердечки), я хочу сделать их красными прим нажатии через js. каждую кнопку перебирать не вариант

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня есть несколько объектов с одним классом(сердечки), я хочу сделать их красными прим нажатии через js.  каждую кнопку перебирать не вариант. добавляю константу через queryselectorALL и получаю массив из этих кнопок. как организовать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая красивая задача) А вам обязательно это делать через JS?) Не хотите потсавить скрытые чекбоксы и по их значениями менять цвет и это будет полностью на CSS?☺️

Comment: через чекбоксы некрасиво, их приходится всё время вставлять, а js делает это автоматически имея просто класс ну или класс

Comment: Это не некрасиво - это вам просто лишний тег не хочутся писать. Пользователю он всё равно не будет виден) Но зато будет эффективнее работать) Ладно чёрт с ним) Что вам конкретно надо? Как менять класс через JS? Или как заполнить само сердечко через CSS св-ва? Если второе, то вам в обязательном порядке надо поделиться с нами вёрсткой (НО ТОЛЬКО СЕРДЕЧКИ), чтобы мы могли хотя бы увидеть  с чем имеем дело

Comment: А ещё очень рекомендую прочитать про делегирование событий - это в разы проще, надёжнее и эффективнее чем каждому элементу отдельно назначать событие. Тем более, если вдруг динамечски добавится сердечко, то на нём уже не отработает событие, т.к. в момент поиска его не было на странице, а вот с помощью делегирования событий эта проблема легко решается

Comment: ну например можно получить коллекцию сердечек, потом через forEach (повесить на каждую addEventListener, и при клике навешивать активный класс

Comment: проблема, в том, что у меня несколько объектов с одинаковым классом, а когда я применяю addeventlistener, то выдаёт ошибку т.к. несколько объектов с одинакомвым классом не могут быть функцией

Comment: Вы же сами нашли проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const element = document.querySelectorAll('.element');

element.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function () {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
}))
```

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
}

.element {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}

.active {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid tomato;

}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="element">Раз</div>
  <div class="element">Два</div>
  <div class="element">Три</div>
  <div class="element">Четыре</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cердечно благодарю